# How can I get an oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection when using hikari

Tags: hikaricp

I need an oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection to directly work with ORACLE's SDO_GEOMETRY.

I have an Object that is of type:
class com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.ConnectionJavassistProxy

My debugger says its value is:
ConnectionJavassistProxy(1082639682) wrapping oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@220c1ab2

Note that T4CConnection implements oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

So if I can get access to it, I will have what I need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);